# JavaScript not running because of jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have some code that I'm using to create a dropdown menu that changes depending on what is checked. The JavaScript and html separated from the page work fine but once its loaded at the same time as the jQuery and everything is placed into a dialog box I receive an error which is like this

I can see this error thru Firebug on my client but it doesn't seem to appear in jsfiddle but when it appears the dropdowns don't work ...

> document.form1a.damage is undefined
> [Break On This Error]
> document.form1a.damage[i].options.length=0;

I have managed to work out this much: that its caused by the dialog box part of the jQuery code, not the other jQuery that I'm using and that once the dialog boxes are removed the dropdown menus work absolutely fine. I have uploaded all me code to JsFiddle

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YTwv/)

Answer (score 0):

Your form is empty when that code executes. Jquery ui dialog will move its entire html structure into its own div (typically at the bottom of the page) with all the applied styling, classes, etc.

To see this in jsfiddle, change the code load event to `no wrap (head)`, it's above the framework select. You will get the error you mention.

Use firebug/chrome inspector to look at the html structure at that time. You have:

```
<form name="form1a" method="post" id="form1a"></form>
<div dialog1></div>
<div dialog2></div>
<div overlay></div>
```

As a solution to the issue, consider giving the selects their own id's and using:

```
document.getElementById('selectDamage0').options.length = 0;
```

... or continue using the by class name and index, etc instead of using the form notation.

**Update:**

Here is a jsfiddle showing another approach, just binding the onchange with jquery and setting the options through that. Commented a bit to show flow -- the function is near the bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/xCMU6/

**Update 2:**

An old way of managing id's at the base level this way is to use a common prefix/suffix. So your first select is `type-0` with `damage-0`. Then to reference the other you swap out the words (or split on -).

Comment: umm i dont quite understand umm is to much to ask u to change in in js fiddle... im sorry its just im quite new to javascript and have been needing alot of help with it

Comment: what u do u mean by                                                                     "As a solution to the issue, consider giving the selects their own id's and using:

document.getElementById('selectDamage0').options.length = 0;

Comment: In jsfiddle on the left sidebar its set to 'onLoad' meaning wait until the html is ready then fire all the javascript which is what `$(function({}))` already does. Change it to `no wrap (head)` to make it act like you are just putting a `<script> ... </script>` before the `<body>`. It then acts like you think it should.

Comment: As a solution it means that line of code `document.form1a` is empty, it doesn't have any elements called `damage` in it as jquery moved all the insides out of it. There are other ways to select an element such as `getElementById` -- I'd google around for an intro to HTML and id/classes/selectors as it's out of scope for a quick answer.

Comment: i understand about id/claseses  the code orginally was set to getElementById but i changed it because i required 2 sets of the dropdown menus and i know that i am unable to have 2 of the same id's on the same page.. how would i be able to have 2 dropdown menus without the issue of 2 confiting id's

Comment: The no wrap is just to "fix" the issue Matthew was mentioning, it's purely related to how jsfiddle works. You need to change your selector from `document.form1a` to another dom selector since the form no longer has any elements.

Comment: how else would i be able to select it because i cannot use an id or a class as i can see.. and im pretty sure a name might not work either ?

Comment: if i used a function to create the dropdown  menu only on opening of the dialog box and i used id's as a selector would that be a possible way to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jsFiddle is wrapping your code in a `$(window).load` function which makes `fill_damage` a variable defined in the `$(window).load` function. Once the `$(window).load` function has finished executing, the `fill_damage` function is no longer in scope, which means you cannot use an `onchange` handler to reference it.

The solution to this is to either:

1. include it in your `$(function)` **and** assign it to a `click` handler using jQuery (recommended since you're already using it) or through more traditional JavaScript methods (like `addListener` (not recommended since you're already using jQuery).
2. or to change your framework selection to `noWrap (head)` or `no wrap (body)`.

I re-wrote your fiddle (with a lot of comments). You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9YTwv/7/

Hope this helps.